# Maintaining local variables between eval of code

Tags: ruby, eval, metaprogramming

Consider the following Ruby code:

```
class Foo
  def bar; 42; end
  def run(code1,code2)
    binding.eval(code1,'c1')
    binding.eval(code2,'c2')
  end
end

Foo.new.run "x=bar ; p x", "p x"
```

The intent is to dynamically evaluate some code—which creates local variables—and then run additional code that has access to those variables. The result is:

```
c2:1:in `run': undefined local variable or method `x' for #<Foo:…> (NameError)
```

Note that the above would only work if the `eval` mutated the binding, which it only does when modifying existing local variables, not creating new variables. I do not necessarily need (or want) each run to mutate the outer binding, I just need to be able to access the previous binding for subsequent code evaluations.

**How can I eval two blocks of code and maintain local variables between them?**

---

<sub>For the curious, the real-world application of this is a [custom tool](http://github.com/Phrogz/RUIC) that can execute a script file and then drop into a REPL. I want the REPL to have access to all local variables created by the script file.</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store the `Binding` and re-use the same one. If you call `binding` repeatedly—even in the same scope—you will get a new binding. So, for the demo function, we can do this:

```
class Foo
  def initialize; @b = binding; end
  def bar; 42; end
  def run(code)
    @b.eval( code, '(yourcode)' )
  end
end

f = Foo.new
f.run "x=bar ; p x"  #=> 42
f.run "p x"          #=> 42
```

Comment: `(@binding ||= binding).eval(code, '(yourcode)')` in the method body works for me - just a bit simpler.

Comment: @August Interesting! That helps a lot. So calling `binding` creates a new binding each time; as long as I create a single Binding and store it, there is no reason to return the binding. Thanks!

Comment: @August I have edited my answer to incorporate your feedback. If you wanted to post as your own answer I would be happy to revert my change and upvote (and possibly accept) your answer.

Comment: You can keep it in your answer :)