# Create blank binding in the scope of an object

Tags: ruby, eval

```ruby
class Foo
  def self.run(n,code)
    foo = self.new(n)
    @env = foo.instance_eval{ binding }
    @env.eval(code)
  end
  def initialize(n)
    @n = n
  end
end

Foo.run( 42, "p @n, defined? foo" )
#=> 42
#=> "local-variable"
```

The sample program above is intended to evaluate arbitrary code within the scope of a `Foo` instance. It does that, but the binding is "polluted" with the local variables from the `code` method. I don't want `foo`, `n`, or `code` to be visible to the eval'd code. The desired output is:

```
#=> 42
#=> nil
```

How can I create a binding that is (a) in the scope of the object instance, but (b) devoid of any local variables?

---

*The reason that I am creating a binding instead of just using `instance_eval(code)` is that in the [real usage](https://github.com/Phrogz/RUIC/blob/456c1034496185f3d3065d35f8fe981cb3b7780f/lib/ruic.rb#L17) I need to [keep the binding around for later usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26811980/maintaining-binding-between-eval-of-code/26812017#26812017), to preserve the local variables created in it.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

so like this? or did i miss something important here?

```
class Foo
  attr_reader :b

  def initialize(n)
    @n = n
    @b = binding
  end

  def self.run(n, code)
    foo  = self.new(n)
    foo.b.eval(code)
  end
end

Foo.run(42, "p @n, defined?(foo)")
# 42
# nil
```

or move it further down to have even less context

```
class Foo
  def initialize(n)
    @n = n
  end

  def b
    @b ||= binding
  end

  def self.run(n, code)
    foo  = self.new(n)
    foo.b.eval(code)
  end
end

Foo.run(42, "p @n, defined?(foo), defined?(n)")
# 42
# nil
# nil
```

Comment: You have removed some of the local variables, but not all: `defined?(n)` is `"local-variable"` because of where you called `binding`. It is cleaner, but it is not blank.

Comment: Yes, the updated version works. Thanks! Note, however, that it creates a new blank binding every time `b` is called. If this is what you want, the answer is perfect. If instead—like me—you want to keep the same binding for accumulating the local variables from each run, you would need to do something like `def b; @b||=binding; end`. I'll give you the acceptance because in some ways using the instance as the storage is more elegant than having a separate object (as in my answer); in other ways this does force a new instance variable on your object that you may not wish to have.

Comment: but in this case binding will have @b defined

Answer (score 2):

**Answer**:

```
module BlankBinding
  def self.for(object)
    @object = object
    create
  end
  def self.create
    @object.instance_eval{ binding }
  end
end
```

**Description**:

In order to get a binding with no local variables, you must call `binding` in a scope without any of them. Calling a method resets the local variables, so we need to do that. However, if we do something like this:

```
def blank_binding_for(obj)
  obj.instance_eval{ binding }
end
```

…the resulting binding will have an `obj` local variable. You can hide this fact like so:

```
def blank_binding_for(_)
  _.instance_eval{ binding }.tap{ |b| b.eval("_=nil") }
end
```

…but this only removes the value of the local variable. (There is no `remove_local_variable` method in Ruby currently.) This is sufficient if you are going to use the binding in a place like IRB or [ripl](https://github.com/cldwalker/ripl) where the `_` variable is set after every evaluation, and thus will run over your shadow.

However, as shown in the answer at top, there's another way to pass a value to a method, and that's through an instance variable (or class variable, or global variable). Since we are using `instance_eval` to shift the `self` to our object, any instance variables we create in order to invoke the method will not be available in the binding.